# Can Delegates point to private methods?

Tags: methods, delegates, c#-3.0, access-modifiers

I have a very straight forward question:

Can delegates point to private methods? I would also like to know if method accessibility modifiers should be taken care of?

Comment: They not only can, they almost always do.  Any "Click" event handler is private.

Comment: @HansPassant so delegates can refer to any method regardless of the method's access modifier?